# ASP.NET: Adding a form to post to another site

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP website and I need to add a form that will post to another site and open in another window.  I can't use JavaScript (which would make it easy).  The issue is that I can only post a few fields to the other site, so I can't just add the inputs and redirect the post back to the other site because all of the ASP info would be posted, too.

Basically, I need to get the following code working (or something equivalent), but I can't add the form tag because of the ASP form.

```
<form id="frm_post" action="https://anothersite.com" target="_blank" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" id="accountnumber" name="accountnumber" value="123456" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

All the fields will be hidden, so it will basically look like a link, but it will be a post request with the specified fields/values.

Thanks.

Comment: Its working correctly, so what is the problem ?

Comment: It will not work on an ASP page... it breaks all the ASP controls because of the nested form tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of nesting the form try moving the inner form tag to be outside/after the asp.net form. 
Then use CSS to reposition the 2nd form so that it looks like it is in the same position visually as it currently does.

Comment: This worked best for me.  I'm using master pages, so I created a new content area outside of the ASP form tag to hold form content.

Answer (score 1):

This actually works:

Add a blank `<form></form>` immediately before the form you would like to submit (`frm_post` in your case)

The `</form>` tag "tricks" asp into not including your *new form* in its self-postback-viewstate-mess, allowing your form to actually post, and the asp form to still function properly.  A little hacky, but totally fixes it.

In my opinion, The two-forms problem is one of the great Achilles Heels of ASP.net

Answer (score 0):

You can not place nested form tags in asp.net. you can place them beside each other but not nested in other form. you should change your forms structure to correct this problem.

Comment: this maybe written in a documentation somewhere, but it certainly is possible. I do it successfully one a week or so.